# Access vba finding type mismatch error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query that is 21 lines of SQL in string call PivotMaster.  When I execute it I get a type mismatch error.  When I hit debug button I see that only the first 14 lines are highlighted in yellow, the last 7 are not.  Does that mean that the error is somewhere in the yellow, of is 14 the max number of lines that can be highlighted? The Having clause is the 21st line and all the data types are correct.

Thanks

Comment: Error most likely in selected command, but it can be in other place, without code and, probably, the database it's hard to help you. Post the code first, mark the row with error and give exact error message

Answer (score 0):

I had missing line continuation characters in the unhighlighted code.  Correct and all the code highlighted with typr mismatch error.